# Checking correct order of values

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a data set that looks similar to the one below.  Basically, I have current prices for three different sizes of an item type.  If the sizes are priced correctly (ie `small<medium<large`) I want to flag them with a “Y” and continue to use the current price.  If they are not priced correctly, I want to flag them with a “N” and use the recommended price.  I know that this is probably a time to use array programming, but my array skills are, admittedly, a bit weak.  There are hundreds of locations, but only one item type.  I currently have the unique locations loaded in a macro variable list.

```
data have;
                input type location $ size $ cur_price rec_price;
cards;
x NY S 4 1
x NY M 5 2
x NY L 6 3
x LA S 5 1
x LA M 4 2
x LA L 3 3
x DC S 5 1
x DC M 5 2
x DC L 5 3
;
run;

proc sql;
                select distinct location into :loc_list from have;
quit;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Next time be careful with `<`.  HTML is legal in questions.  :)  Pay attention to the bottom 'preview', which is updated live.

Comment: thanks Joe.. i'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: I also improved the title, feel free to improve it further.  The title should describe your problem, not how you want to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to use an array here...proc transpose and some data step logic
can easily solve this problem.  Arrays are very useful (gotta admit, I'm not entirely 
comfortable with them either), but in a situation where you have that many locations, 
I think transpose is better.

Does the code below accomplish your goal?

```
/*sorts to get ready for transpose*/
proc sort data=have;
    by location;
run;

/*transpose current price*/
proc transpose data=have out=cur_tran prefix=cur_price;
    by location;
    id size;
    var cur_price;
run;

/*transpose recommended price*/
proc transpose data=have out=rec_tran prefix=rec_price;
    by location;
    id size;
    var rec_price;
run;

/*merge back together*/
data merged;
    merge cur_tran rec_tran;
    by location;
run;

/*creates flags and new field for final price*/
data want;
    set merged;
    if cur_priceS<cur_priceM<cur_priceL then 
        do;
        FLAG='Y';
        priceS=cur_priceS;
        priceM=cur_priceM;
        priceL=cur_priceL;
        end;
    else do;        
        FLAG='N';
        priceS=rec_priceS;
        priceM=rec_priceM;
        priceL=rec_priceL;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how arrays would help here.  How about just checking using `dif` to queue the last record's price and verify it (could also `retain` the last price if you prefer).  Make sure the dataset's properly sorted `by type location descending size`, then:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by type location descending size;            *S > M > L alphabetically;
  retain price_check;
  if not first.location and dif(cur_price) lt 0 then price_check=1; 
                                               *if dif < 0 then cur rec is smaller;
  else if first.location then price_check=0;   *reset it;
  if last.location;
  keep type location price_check;
run;
```

Then merge that back to your original dataset `by type location`, and use the other price if `cur_price=1`.

Comment: Note, if I were really doing this I would use a `DoW` loop to avoid remerging - but don't see a need to introduce that here.

Comment: appreciate the quick response here Joe - this gives me exactly what I need when i run the code.  I'm a less seasoned in SAS so I am able to follow the answer from pyll a little easier

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could do it in a single query which is almost a re-statement of your requirements.

```
Proc sql; 
         create  table want as 
         select  * 

/*              Basically, I have current prices for three different sizes of an item type. 
                 If the sizes are priced correctly (ie small<medium<large)  */ 
         ,       case 
                         when    max ( case when size eq 'S' then cur_price end) 
                         lt      max ( case when size eq 'M' then cur_price end) 
                         and     max ( case when size eq 'M' then cur_price end) 
                         lt      max ( case when size eq 'L' then cur_price end) 

/*                      I want to flag them with a “Y” and continue to use the current price */ 
                         then    'Y' 

/*                      If they are not priced correctly, 
                         I want to flag them with a “N” and use the recommended price.   */ 
                         else    'N' 
                 end                             as      Cur_Price_Sizes_Correct 

         ,       case 
                         when    calculate Cur_Price_Correct     eq      'Y' 
                         then    cur_price 
                         else    rec_price 
                 end                             as      Price 

        From    have 

        Group   by      Type 
                 ,       Location 
         ; 
Quit;
```